# How to save Vue router params in order to prevent user from manually modifying?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am passing some parameters in my Vue routes

```
{ path: '/page/:slug/:tab', name: 'page', component: page('page.vue') },
```

So when I use the specific path, the URL looks like this: [www.test.com/page/slug-text/active](http://www.test.com/page/slug-text/active)
Where slug = slug-text and tab = active

It works fine and I use those params in order to fetch specific data from database using "slug".
I also have 4 tabs in the page so I am using the "tab" parameter to display the current tab.

```
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.slug = this.$route.params.slug || null
      this.currentTab = this.$route.params.tab || null
      this.$store.dispatch('data/fetchSingle', this.slug)
    },
  }
```

The issue I am facing here is when a user decides to change the URL params manually.
For example when someone manually changes the URL from this:

```
www.test.com/page/slug-text/active
```

to this:

```
www.test.com/page/slug-whatever/whatever
```

That means the params will be changed as well and it affects my Vue data.
Eg. The current tab won't work as I do not have a tab named "whatever"

Can anyone please let me know what will be a proper way of preventing this problem?

Comment: This is not a problem, per se. The idea of having a route is that you can actually have such link created (although with valid data) so they can work as regular links. What you need to do is validate that the parameters are valid and if not valid, return an error. See here as an example of adding parameter match and then everything else is a 404 error: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route

Comment: Thx for the answer. I can check if the data are valid or not, this is not a problem. I am just thinking whether it is ok to let the users manually changing the params and thus, causing a 404 error. Will that be a proper solution? To show an error message when params in the URL are manually modified by the user? @NelsonRodriguez

Comment: IMHO yes, it's OK to show an error. Because you allow the user to manually (if they wish) to move to some other route, which can be very convenient. If they type something erroneously, then it's nice that the page tells them it's not found (or any appropriate error)

Answer (score 2):

When using `Vue.js`, it is possible to observe route's change. You can achieve it by adding the hooks `beforeRouteEnter`, `beforeRouteLeave` and `beforeRouteUpdate`. You can check your URL in these hooks, before the page is rendered. If the parameters are not correct, you can either redirect to a error page, or set your component to the "error" state, and warn the user.

I suggest you to read following doc:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html